# How do I upgrade my rails routes with member exceptions AND collections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I want to do some routing and can't figure it out.
(I'm migrating from 2.3.9 to 4.2.6!)

**Limited Members, Some Collection**

In 2.3 With

```
map.resources :contact, :only => :index, :collection => { :send_mail => :post  }
```

I got...

```
send_mail_contact POST /contact/send_mail(.:format) {:action=>"send_mail", :controller=>"contact"}
    index_contact GET  /contact/index(.:format)     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"contact"}
    contact_index GET  /contact(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"contact"}
```

So I've tried

```
resources :contact, only: [:index] do
  collection do
    post 'send_mail'
    # :index => :get, 
    # :send_mail => :post  }
  end
end
```

which gives...

```
send_mail_contact_index POST   /contact/send_mail(.:format)   contact#send_mail
          contact_index GET    /contact(.:format)             contact#index
```

??  How do I get rid of the _index for send_mail?

Then I tried

```
with_options(only: [:index]) do |opt|
  opt.resources :contact do
    collection do
      post 'send_mail'
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives the same!

```
send_mail_contact_index POST   /contact/send_mail(.:format)   contact#send_mail
          contact_index GET    /contact(.:format)             contact#index
```

===============================

**No Members, Collection Only**

Also I have a collection of pages (non-static)...

In 2.3 With

```
map.resources  :info, :except => :all, :collection => { 
       :about => :get,  :usage => :get, :privacy => :get, :kudos => :get }
```

I got...

```
privacy_info GET    /info/privacy(.:format)   {:controller=>"info", :action=>"privacy"}
  usage_info GET    /info/usage(.:format)     {:controller=>"info", :action=>"usage"}
  kudos_info GET    /info/kudos(.:format)     {:controller=>"info", :action=>"kudos"}
  about_info GET    /info/about(.:format)     {:controller=>"info", :action=>"about"}
```

So I tried

```
resources :info, only: [] do
  collection do
    get 'about'
    get 'usage'
    get 'privacy'
    get 'kudos'
  end
end
```

which gives...

```
    about_info_index GET    /info/about(.:format)          info#about
    usage_info_index GET    /info/usage(.:format)          info#usage
  privacy_info_index GET    /info/privacy(.:format)        info#privacy
    kudos_info_index GET    /info/kudos(.:format)          info#kudos
```

Again I have the _index! about_info_index_path instead of about_info_path.

Lots of answers about using except and only, but Not with collections.

Is there a bug somewhere, undocumented feature, or am I really missing something?

Thank you,
Dirk

Answer (score 0):

resources needs to be in PLURAL by convention.
So use the following :

```
resources :contacts, only: [:index] do
  collection do
    post 'send_mail'
    # :index => :get, 
    # :send_mail => :post  }
  end
end
```

Output :

```
$ bundle exec rake routes | grep "contact"
send_mail_contacts POST   /contacts/send_mail(.:format)  contacts#send_mail                           
contacts GET    /contacts(.:format) contacts#index
```